# How to make navbar dropdown list full-width on mobile without bootstrap

Tags: html, css

My goal is to make the dropdown list that is displayed when I click on the #myDropdown div full width on mobile but what I've tried so far hasn't worked. I am not using bootstrap (nor can I).

```css
/* DROPDOWN */

#navbar_reservas {
  height: 70px;
}

#reservas_left {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}

#reservas_right {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}

#inner_reservas_left {
  float: right;
}

#inner_reservas_right {
  float: left;
}

#totalprice {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar_reservas .dropbtn,
#navbar_reservas #dudas {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}

#drop4 {
  display: none;
}

#drop5 {
  display: none;
}

#drop6 {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown_reservas .dropbtn {
  height: 80px;
}

.dropdown-content_reservas {
  position: fixed;
  color: #333;
}

.dropbtn {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#myDropdown {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myDropdown li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar_reservas">
  <div id="reservas_left">
    <div class="nav-item_reservas" id="inner_reservas_left">
      <a id="dudas" href="tel:555555555">
                    ¿Dudas?
                    <br />555 555 555
                </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="reservas_right">
    <div class="dropdown_reservas nav-item_reservas" id="inner_reservas_right">
      <div class="dropbtn">
        TOTAL
        <br /><span id="totalprice">0,00€</span>
        <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content_reservas" id="myDropdown">
        <ul id="dropul" class="unoul">
          <li id="drop1"></li>
          <li id="drop2"></li>
          <li id="drop3"></li>
          <li id="drop4"></li>
          <li id="drop5"></li>
          <li id="drop6"></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If I add:

```
@media (max-width: 760px){
    #myDropdown{
        width:100%;
    }
    #reservas_right {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

The dropdown div does become full width as I want, but of course, now the #myDropdown div falls on a new row below, so the divs are not centered anymore, but on two full-width rows which is not what I want. I want only one row with the two divs centered which is what I have, but I have no idea how to make the dropdown list full width while keeping its parent div 49% div. And only do this on mobile! It sounds complicated I know. I hope you guys can understand what I mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML

```
<div id="navbar_reservas">
<div id="reservas_left">
<div class="nav-item_reservas" id="inner_reservas_left">
  <a id="dudas" href="tel:555555555">
                ¿Dudas?
                <br />555 555 555
            </a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="reservas_right">
<div class="dropdown_reservas nav-item_reservas" id="inner_reservas_right">
  <div class="dropbtn" onclick="divhide()">
    TOTAL
    <br /><span id="totalprice">0,00€</span>
    <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-content_reservas" id="myDropdown">
<ul id="dropul" class="unoul">
  <li id="drop1">1</li>
  <li id="drop2">2</li>
  <li id="drop3">3</li>
  <li id="drop4">4</li>
  <li id="drop5">5</li>
  <li id="drop6">6</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

The CSS

```
/* DROPDOWN */

#navbar_reservas {
height: 70px;
}

#reservas_left {
float: left;
width: 49%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
}

#reservas_right {
float: left;
width: 49%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
}

#inner_reservas_left {
float: right;
}

#inner_reservas_right {
float: left;
}

#totalprice {
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar_reservas .dropbtn,
#navbar_reservas #dudas {
font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}

#drop4 {
display: none;
}

#drop5 {
display: none;
}

#drop6 {
display: none;
}

.dropdown_reservas .dropbtn {
height: 80px;
}

.dropdown-content_reservas {
position: fixed;
color: #333;
}

.dropbtn {
margin-left: 50px;
}

#myDropdown {
text-align: left;
padding: 1%;
padding-right: 3%;
font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
margin-top: 2%;
list-style-type: none;
display: none;
float: right;
width: 49%;
margin-left: 51%;
}

#myDropdown li {
list-style-type: none;
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
#myDropdown {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
display: none;
margin-left: 0%;
}
}
```

The JavaScript to show and hide the dropdown menu

```
function divhide() {
if (document.getElementById('myDropdown').style.display == 'block') {
document.getElementById('myDropdown').style.display = 'none';}
else {
document.getElementById('myDropdown').style.display = 'block';}
}
```

Basically I've moved the div outside of the container and copied over the desktop CSS for the desktop version and created new CSS for the mobile version. Your primary display for that you see is on all screens is on the same row but the drop down div had to be on a separate row unless you want to do something with a lightbox for instance. The JavaScript is just there as a basic implementation of activating the drop down menu. This is a basic answer for you and may not be what you want in the end.